# Primefaces Datatable - Drag & Drop on specific columns

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to have a datatable on a primefaces datatable but only for specific columns (first three columns should be fixed) but draggableColumns property sets all of them draggable. I have found nothing in the specification about that how to skip some columns. Anybody had similar issues or has an idea how could I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, sorry. Fixed colums are indeed still draggable. File a feature request in the PrimeFaces issue list